# Looking for a Laravel CRUD generator that supports creation of nested "inline" models

Tags: laravel, user-interface, crud

There are a lot of CRUD generators for Laravel, but I can't find a "golden feature": I often work with relationships that should not be presented with a master->detail interface; for example, I'm talking about the creation of questionnaires: you have a QUESTIONNAIRE element that contains (1-n) some QUESTIONS; these questions have (1-n) some possible ANSWERS.

This cannot be built with a master -> detail -> detail UX simply because it's uncomfortable. The perfect interface is to have a list of the questionnaire (master) and a single page to edit one questionnaire (detail) that allows to edit the questionnaire itself (title, etc.) and the creation of QUESTIONS and their ANSWERS, in the same page.

Is there a CRUD generator that helps developers with the creation of an interface like this?

I'm already working with these interfaces, built from scratch with Laravel and custom views (see the sample screen below) but I'm sure there's a quicker way to reach the same target with a prebuilt CRUD generator, simply from the laravel models and **describing** how the interface should be.

[image: questionnaire]